# textpos for all pages - environment usage

Tags: environments

I'm trying to put some text on topleft for every page of my appendix. I use textpos but it adds the text only one page. I thought I might use an environment and put the appendix between this environment but it didnt work, resulting just one page with the text I want. I want APPENDIX text in all of my appendix pages. How can I do it?

```
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{40mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{18mm}
% start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newenvironment{band}{

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
\textbf{APPENDIX A}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{3}(0,1)
\textbf{APPE\\NDIX}
\end{textblock}
}
```

Comment: Your environment definition is incomplete. You should always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that is compilable. I would solve your issue by placing the `textblock`(s) into a macro and add this macro to either header or footer. Then it will be processed for every page. There also should be similar questions with suitable answers around.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Defining a macro in header worked.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{40mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{18mm}
% start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\band}{
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,0)
\textbf{APPENDIX A}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,1)
\textbf{APPE\\NDIX}
\end{textblock}
}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\band \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{}
\include{manual/manual}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) for that purpose. It can be used to define code to be executed for each page, such as including pictures or printing text boxes. This can be started when the appendix starts.

Why `atbegshi`? The implementation of `textpos` requires [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi), and `atbegshi` is a modern reimplementation of `everyshi`.

However, `textpos` offers an easy interface. You could use it for example also with `fancyhdr` or `scrpage2` to print a text box in the header of each page at an absolute position.

Another way would be using TikZ and the `current page` node for absolute positioning on a page. Here are examples, with headings packages to repeat that for page ranges: [Fancy chapter headings with TikZ](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/fancy-chapter-tikz/).